# How to make sprite kit object not affected by gravity?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a sprite which I want to react to every part of the physics simulation except for gravity. I can't make it's `dynamic` property false otherwise it won't react to impulses and forces, but I still need gravity for the rest of the scene. How do I turn off gravity for one sprite?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
spriteName.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was something like that, but I thought it was "isaffectedbygravity" so it wouldn't show up.

Comment: @user2391236 Just as a heads up, the `is` prefix is used for getters, so if you want it to show up as a part of the syntax highlighting, it has to be used in an assignment or evaluation. Also, you should upvote and accept answers that, well, answered your question.

Comment: It's so obvious... that I didn't even thought of type that in XCode ! Thanks !